# Laravel star ratings with font awesome

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, font-awesome, laravel-5.5

I am retrieving an average rating on my batsmen and currently displaying it as the number itself out of 5. I want to replace the number of the average rating with font awesome stars, so if its 4.63/5 then show 4.63 font awesome stars out of 5 rather than the number i'm currently showing. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: 100 / 5 * 4.63 = 92.6%

Answer (score 2):

For example, only with percent:

```
<div class="star-rating" title="75%">
    <div class="back-stars">
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>

        <div class="front-stars" style="width: 75%">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style for star rating

```
/*---------- star rating ----------*/
.star-rating {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.back-stars {
    display: flex;
    color: #bb5252;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #843a3a;
}
.front-stars {
    display: flex;
    color: #FFBC0B;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #d29b09;
    top: 0;
}
```

```js
var frontStars = document.getElementsByClassName("front-stars")[0];
var percentage = 100 / 5 * 4.63;
frontStars.style.width = percentage + "%";

var rating = document.getElementsByClassName("star-rating")[0];
rating.title = +(4.63.toFixed(2)) + " out of " + 5;
```

```css
*{margin, padding:0}
/*---------- star rating ----------*/
.star-rating {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.back-stars {
    display: flex;
    color: #bb5252;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 10px #843a3a;
}
.front-stars {
    display: flex;
    color: #FFBC0B;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #d29b09;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f4e64b7c17.js"></script>

<div class="star-rating">
    <div class="back-stars">
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        
        <div class="front-stars">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [this jquery library](https://github.com/glix/j-plugin/tree/master/Simple-jQuery-Star-Rating-System-For-Bootstrap-3) to add a star rating system when needed.

1. **The Source:** I include the jquery and style in a partial view that I only add to pages with the star system.

   `<script src="{{ asset('/vendor/Simple-jQuery-Star-Rating-System-For-Bootstrap-3/js/star-rating.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link href="{{ asset('vendor/Simple-jQuery-Star-Rating-System-For-Bootstrap-3/css/star-rating.css')}}" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`
2. **Form Item:** Then I add it to my page using the

   `<div class="form-group">
       <label for="text" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Rating:</label>
       <input name='rate' id="input-2c" class="rating" min="0" max="5" step="0.5" data-size="sm" data-symbol="&#xf005;" data-glyphicon="false" data-rating-class="rating-fa">
   </div>`

To set a default value, or to show the existing value, you just need to add the value="" attribute to the input.  The plugin does the rest.

Comment: hello, how to get name='rate' value while input or rate something different